# Excel file with macro somethimes not opening

Tags: excel, vba

I have an macro enabled excel file, which, after using it few times, not works anymore or lagging as hell.

It's added to trust center etc. Only 2 things helps to run that file normally 1) restart pc; 2) start excel, then make new workbook, then open that file.Maybe someone have any idea where is the problem?It's added to trust center etc.

Comment: Please share the code. Perhaps it is in the code.

Comment: in trust center you need to do 3 things. trusted location tab > add new location button, macro settings tab > Enable all macro... and check trust access to the vba..., Message Bar tab > click Show the Message Bar in all applications... . if the problem is security it will solve it. else keep looking. and you can do all the above from new excel file, not the one that is not open.

Comment: @FreddyMeijer nop, problem is not in code. And code is pretty big for posting 
(~1200 rows), there is a lot of functions. I beleave there is something with "cashe", which is stay don't know where and windows remember it

Comment: @xShen all those steps are done.. Problem is not here, unfortunatelly :/

Comment: well , you could try to open the file with another workbook ,go to vba IDE then open the ThisWorkbook module of the xlsm file , and comment all in Workbook_Open() sub or  Workbook_Activate() or anything that fire when the file start . if after that  he will open , start uncomment line by line until the problematic line and fix it .  else keep looking....